# How to change the order of the timers?

Tags: clock, android-one

How can I change the order the timers are displayed in the default clock application? I've got about two dozens of them and it seems I can only add new ones in front and not change the order.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Maybe use a timer app like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hybrid.stopwatch)? I haven't used the app, suggestion based on Play Store description

Comment: This depends on the Clock application itself, which can also depend on the device model since manufacturers can customize their own stock apps. If such a feature doesn't exist, then the solution is to use a 3rd-party clock app.

Comment: @AndrewT.Device is an BQ running Android One,